# Using R to scrape play-by-play data

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am currently trying to scrape the play-by-play entries from the following link:
https://www.basket.fi/basketball-finland/competitions/game/?game_id=4677793&season_id=110531&league_id=4

I used the SelectorGadget to determine CSS selectors and ended up with '//td'. However when I attempt to scrape the data using this, html_nodes() returns an empty list and thus the following code returns an error.

```
library("rvest")

url <- "https://www.basket.fi/basketball-finland/competitions/game/?game_id=4677793&season_id=110531&league_id=4"

play_by_play <- url %>% 
  read_html %>%  
  html_node(xpath='//td') %>% 
  html_table()
play_by_play
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot get the table simply because there are no table in the website(see the source).
It there are any tables, you can get it with following code.

```
library("rvest")

url <- "https://www.basket.fi/basketball-finland/competitions/game/?game_id=4677793&season_id=110531&league_id=4"

play_by_play <- url %>% 
  read_html %>%  
  html_table() 
play_by_play
```

Answer (score 0):

The data in the page you are loading is loaded with Javascript, so when you used `read_html`, you are not seeing what you want. If you check "view the source", you will not see table or td in the source page.

What you can do is using other options like Rselenium to get the page source, and if you want to use rvest later you can scrape from the source you get.

```
library(rvest)
library(Rselenium)

url <- "https://www.basket.fi/basketball-finland/competitions/game/?game_id=4677793&season_id=110531&league_id=4"

rD<- rsDriver()

remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

play_by_play <-read_html(unlist(remDr$getPageSource()),encoding="UTF-8") %>%
  html_nodes("td")

remDr$close()
rm(remDr, rD)
gc()
```